# Resize events of children are called sooner than the resize events of the parents

Tags: qt, user-interface

In a `QWidget` application, there are some parameters I change when the main window is resized, and I would like to use them in the resize events of some individual elements.

However, the resize events of the children seem to trigger sooner than the resize event of the parent.

The obvious approach would be to just emit a signal from the main window's `resizeEvent` and connect it to all the widgets which need it, but there will be lots of such widgets, so I would like to avoid this if possible. Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Check if the parent already has the correct size. It might not have received the resize event yet, but might be sized correctly.

Comment: @KubaOber : It probably has, but that won't help me. What I need is that I would like to make some decisions in the parent's resize event, instead of having to write that same code (checking the size of the parent and doing calculations on it) in the resize event of every child.

Comment: Then all you need is to watch the children's resize events, set a flag, react to the resize, and clear the flag when the parent finally receives the resize. Qt makes it very easy to get notified when children are added, so this code will be entirely universal and can be in a separate `QObject` class, emitting an "early resize" signal. Clean and easy. You can even make it so that the parent receives the resize event early if you synthesize the event and then filter out the real one.

Comment: @KubaOber : My problem is, that I have to run resizing-related code in the children (preferably in their resizeEvent) after the parent's resize event finished. So I have to emit signals again, to every child, to call their event a second time. This is what I wanted to avoid in the first place.

Comment: Once you start filtering events, you will catch the first child resize event, and before the event handler starts executing, you will deliver a synthetic resize event to the parent. The parent then does its computations. The event handler returns to your filter, and you then release the event to the child. The child event handler runs, and sees the parent with current computed values. The code to do that is almost shorter than my comments, I'm trying hard to get you to write it first :)

Comment: Alternatively, you can store copies of all the child resize events in the filter and filter them out, collecting them until the parent gets its original resize event. Then deliver them after the parent's resize event has been processed.

Comment: @KubaOber : Ok, I got it. When you wrote about "filtering it out" I thought you meant manually, with a simple if in the event, now I see you meant something like `QObject::eventFilter`. I'll give it a try.